# No mini ToC appearing

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, minitoc

First of all, I am not a good user of Latex.

I am trying to put a little "table of contents" in every chapter of my manuscript.

I used the `minitoc` package and also the `hyperref`.

This is the what I have for now

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,german,english]{babel}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[]{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0},
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black}
\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}    
\frontmatter
\input{head/titlepage.tex}
\include{head/dedication}

\setcounter{page}{0}
\input{head/acknowledgements}
\include{head/preface}
\include{head/abstracts}

\dominitoc

\tableofcontents

\phantomsection

\include{main/introduction}
\include{main/ch1}

\end{document}
```

and in every chapter file I used the `\minitoc` command

```
\chapter{}
\minitoc
```

The problem is that no mini ToC appears after the chapter name in the PDF file.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you read the manual?

Comment: Please provide a compilable document that has this issue, not just non-contigious fragments

Comment: @TeXnician What's that on the line just above `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: If I collect your snippets and turn them into a complete example, I do get minitocs in each chapter. Can you make a single, complete document (a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that demonstrates your problem, as Christian asked for earlier?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're right, haven't seen it there. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: This is the what I have for now

Comment: Well, we don't have any of the files you `\include` of course, but if remove all those, and add `\chapter{}
\minitoc
\section{}
\section{}`, I do get a minitoc at the start of that chapter (after compiling twice).  Can you make an example that doesn't rely on other files? Perhaps also add `\listfiles` right before `\documentclass`, and add the `.log` file to your question as well.

Comment: Is there any news here? We cannot reproduce your issue with the code given. Please make the example compilable (create a subfolder called `wombt`  and test your example in there).